# Assignment Overview Explanation

Tags: java, oop

I have an assignment for school. I find the description to be quite vague... If anyone would read over it and give me their interpretation or simply explain each method in words other than the teachers it would be greatly appreciated. The assignment asks as follows... Note: I am simply finding his descriptions too vague. So no im not asking for code.thanks.

```
The players will be children of the following (partially defined) class:

public abstract class Player implements Comparable{
   public String name;   // name of player
   public    int id;     // identifier for the player
   protected int wins;   
   protected int losses;
   protected int ties;

   public abstract String play(Player opponent);
   // returns one of "rock", "paper", or "scissors"

   public void update(String myGesture, 
                      String opponentGesture,
                      Player opponent);
   // this method will update the player's stats 
   // (wins, losses, ties) based on the gestures (inputs)
   // for a recent game played against opponent (also input)

   public Player(String name, int id){...}
   // constructor that initializes player's name and id
You will need to fill in the code for the constructor and the update methods for the Player class. You can add other "hidden" attributes and methods as you wish (Note: if you add things to Player, be sure it is something that ALL children classes will also use). You will also need to implement three classes that extend the Player class:

public class SimplePlayer extends Player{...}
// A SimplePlayer will always play the same 
// gesture (either rock, paper, or scissors)
// in every game it plays, regardless
// of who its opponent is.  The gesture is 
// randomly chosen when the SimplePlayer is created.


public class RandomPlayer extends Player{...}
// A RandomPlayer will always play a random
// gesture (rock, paper, or scissors) in 
// every game it plays, regardless of who 
// its opponent is.  


public class SmartPlayer extends Player{...}
// A SmartPlayer will try to use past knowledge
// of games played against a particular 
// opponent when playing them again.
You can add any hidden attributes and methods to the children classes as you wish.
```

EDIT: Since this class implements  Comparable, would the play() be the method comparing the different gestures?

Comment: The site is mostly for code. This sounds like something you should ask your teacher about.

Comment: Unless you have specific questions we will not be able to help you.  This is not a place for *Java to plain English* translations.  For example, do you know what `abstract class` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try restating the obvious (?) here. The teacher has provided you an abstract class `Player` and asked you to implement `SimplePlayer` and `RandomPlayer` classes. You are supposed to implement the respective constructors, and also implement the abstract and update methods .

The `SimplePlayer` class needs to be bootstrapped with a random gesture. You need to pick one of the gestures, either rock, scissors or paper, randomly and return it as an output of `play` method consistently. This means that regardless of what the opponent strategy is `SimplePlayer`'s need to remain the same.

On contrary `RandomPlayer` needs to return a random strategy each time; specifically speaking, the `play` method needs to return a random one.

The `update(...)` method is probably the interesting one. Depending on current players and opponents strategy you need to update the outcome. If you are not familiar with the rules, please refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors). Simplistically speaking, you might have to have bunch of `if..else` blocks to compare the current and opponent player strategies.

Hope this helps, and good luck with the implementation.

Comment: can you please see update and give me your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I reworded what he asked for in my own words, not much else we can do.

- play()  returns whatever gesture the player chooses.
- update()  determines who won, and adds + 1 to their win, loss, or
           tie depending on the gesture(s).
- Player()  initialize the player name and id
- SimplePlayer()  initialize a gesture to be used. This will remain
                 constant
- RandomPLayer()  initializes a gesture to be random on every game
                 it plays.
- SmartPlayer()  chooses a gesture based on what gesture the
                opposite player usually uses.